# cpplinter in github actions

Tags: c++, github, github-actions, linter

I want to install auto-checking my code with help of cpplint in Github actions.

I try to install it in workflows file like that:

```
- name: Install cpplint
      working-directory: ${{runner.workspace}}/uast      
      shell: bash         
      run: |         
          pip install wheel
          pip install cpplint
```

After this code block I try to run cpplint:

```
- name: cpplint
      working-directory: ${{runner.workspace}}/uast      
      shell: bash         
      run: cpplint --recursive --exclude=source/catch.hpp --filter=-legal/copyright,-build/include_subdir source/*
```

But after successful installation (in the first block) I got "line 1: cpplint: command not found" in the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `python -m cpplint`:

```yaml
- name: cpplint
      working-directory: ${{runner.workspace}}/uast      
      shell: bash         
      run: python -m cpplint --recursive --exclude=source/catch.hpp --filter=-legal/copyright,-build/include_subdir source/*
```

Modules installed over pip are not recognized as system level command.